# Is Google Home integration supports arm Night mode

Tags: google-smart-home

I want to integrate my security system with Google smart home. Right now it supports away and stay mode. Will it support arm night mode also?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your own custom integration, you could use the `[Scene]`[1](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7029585?hl=en#zippy=%2Cbedtime) trait to create a night mode for your security system.

If you are just looking to set up controls on a preexisting security system that is compatible with Google Assistant, you could set up a [custom routine](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7029585?hl=en#zippy=%2Cbedtime) to arm your system in the appropriate configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Google is providing the available arm Options. I have added armnight as one of the option. So my skill supports arm night also.